# What should you do when people keep extending questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

Take [Visual viewport vs Layout viewport on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344886/question-on-viewport) for example. He keeps asking for new information in the comments, even when I have answered his initial question.

This person has also re-asked the same question or aspects of it again in new questions.

How should one approach responding to comments of this ilk? How can you do so such that the initial answer to the original question would be accepted?

Comment: I asked about this some time ago: [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478)

Answer (score 6):

I normally suggest at the point that it is clear that the question has been extended (or rather that a *new* question has come up), that the OP ask a new question.

Something to the tune of:

```
Looks like time for a new question...
```

Or:

```
That looks like a new question to me - perhaps you should post it as one.
```

Answer (score 5):

In general, **the comments should be edited back in to the question if they end up containing essential information about the question.**

If the comments diverge wildly into related questions and/or tangents, I would shut them down and stop responding until they ask their other related questions properly.

Feel free to flag this sort of thing for moderator attention if it is an extreme case.

Comment: That makes sense. 'Course, someone needs to edit the original question, and if that's someone other than the original author then that's a whole other kettle of fish (for which I can't seem to find a relevant meta-stack-overflow question on, either :) )